# Returning list in chunks webapi

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, python-requests

My list is too large to be sent back to the client as a HTTP GET response as I am getting a 414 error.  I was wondering how I could go about sending my list in smaller chunks rather than sending the whole thing which gives me a 404 error?  I was thinking about using  `PushStreamContent()` but not sure if this is the way to go?  My client application is a python standalone console app, so there shouldn't be any imposed limits on the size of the response on client size(I think).  The 414 error is probably because the data I am sending back to the client is too large as I am sending code scripts back as well as other meta data about the scripts.

Here is my webapi method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ScriptObject> GetDatasourceScripts(long? id)
    {

        var device = db.devices.Find(id);
        if (device == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var subgroupDevID = db.deviceSubGroups.Where(sub => sub.deviceSubID == device.deviceSubGroupID).Select(subDevID => subDevID.deviceGroupID).FirstOrDefault();
        var companyID = db.deviceGroups.Where(main => main.deviceGroupID == subgroupDevID).Select(cID => cID.deviceCompanyID).FirstOrDefault();

        //Load the list of devices and 
        DatasourceViewModel dsVM = new DatasourceViewModel();
        LoadDataToViewModel(ref dsVM, companyID);


        //we pass the company ID in because we only want that company to see their 
        return ScriptCompiler.Compile(device, dsVM, companyID);
    }
```

and here is my python request

```
def GetDatasourceScripts(urlParameters):
    result = requests.get(constURLString + "/" + str(urlParameters))
    print result.text
    data = json.loads(result.text)
    return data
```

Comment: HTTP 414 means your __request__ URI is too long, not your response. How many parameters are you passing to the server in `urlParameters`?

Comment: I am only passing in one parameter the only parameter that is passes through is '2' @Brett here is the output of my print, when I print out the url http://172.16.1.4:53658/api/DevicesAPI/2

Comment: @Brett I have pasted the whole URL above

Comment: What web server are you running? Have you tried a POST instead of a GET?

Comment: @Brett I am running on IIS7 on server 2008 R2, If I do a post, do I just decorate the api method with a HttpPost? and change requests to a post, and everything else stays the same

Comment: @Brett tried a post and it didnt work

Comment: Without more information it's difficult to help. I have the feeling that it's your WebAPI setup. Are you sure you're using the correct URL? Is your controller named `DevicesAPIController`? If you put a breakpoint inside your `GetDatasourceScripts()` function and debug it, does the code run?

Comment: As a side note, I would not use type `long` for your `id` parameter in `GetDatasourceScripts()`. Use `int` instead.

Comment: @Brett yes it hits the webapi, I just put some print statements in my python code and it seems to be running twice one of which brings back data, and the other bringing back an error 414